# Passing template classes as arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have two template classes FibonacciHeap and Adapter. Both of them have the same interface.

```
template< typename PRIO, typename VALUE, typename CMP = std::less<PRIO> >
class FibonacciHeap;

template<typename PRIO,typename VALUE >
class BinaryHeap;
```

I have another function `dijkstra`. It can use either `BinaryHeap<double,int>` or `FibonacciHeap<double,int>` as its priority queue. I want to pass the type of priority queue as argument.

How can I do that? I know writing an abstract class is an option, but I don't really want to do that. I am looking for other options.

Comment: Can you make dijkstra to be templated function?

Comment: Make `dijkstra` a function template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is functionally good, but a bit unusual.

The usual solution avoids the argument:

```
template <class H> int dijkstra()
{
    H heap;
}
```

You call the function passing the intended heap type.

```
int dist0 = dijkstra<FibonacciHeap<double,int>>();
int dist1 = dijkstra<BinaryHeap<double,int>>();
```

As an alternative, use a template template parameter:

```
template <template H<class, class>> int dijkstra()
{
    H<double, int> heap;
}
int dist0 = dijkstra<FibonacciHeap>();
int dist1 = dijkstra<BinaryHeap>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make dijkstra a templated function.

```
template <class H>
int dijkstra(H heap)
{
  // just use heap
}
```

You can call this function like that:

```
FibonacciHeap<double,int> heapFibo;
BinaryHeap<double,int> heapBina;

int dist0 = dijkstra(heapFibo);
int dist1 = dijkstra(heapBina);
```

The template magic is done by the compiler.

Comment: Can I pass FibonacciHeap<double,int> or BinaryHeap<double,int> objects to dijkstra? I'm not very thorough with templates.

Comment: I also want to use `BinaryHeap<double,int>::item` in dijkstra. Will H::item work?

Comment: you might have to use typename there, is BinaryHeap<double,int>::item a type?

Comment: @user3349665 Yes, if both heaps have an ::item. Otherwise the compiler will complain.

Comment: Then `item` is a dependent name, and you need a `typename`. Otherwise the compiler won't know that `H::item` is a type until it sees `H==BinaryHeap`, and that's too late.